# iOS Destroy UI when app is in background

Tags: ios, user-interface, background, core-location

I'm using CoreLocation to use my app in background.
More precisely, I'm using Significant changes (`startmonitoringsignificantlocationchanges`) or Always On (`startupdatinglocation`) depending on server config.

On these two cases, application lifecycle is different :

- With `startmonitoringsignificantlocationchanges` application is registered to OS, and the app is frozen or killed by OS. It will be waked up when a new location event will be received, and `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` will be called with a specific launch key
- With `startupdatinglocation`, application will run until `stopupdatinglocation` is called. Then application will be frozen until the OS kill the app when more memory is needed

**My question**

I'm using a SDK (developed by my company) which should run in background base on CoreLocation services. The SDK is initialized and attached to the `UIApplicationDelegate` class.

I would like to kill all UI elements after a delay in background to avoid useless data processing in UI (timers, refresh, callbacks, ...), because the app is running in background with `startUpdatingLocation`.

UI Will be launched (from zero) later in `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

Here is what I tried :

1/ Removing automatic storyboard launch in project settings

2/ Start the storyboard manually in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
// Instantiate the initial view controller object from the storyboard
UIStoryboard *story = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
_window = [[UIWindow alloc] init];
_window.rootViewController = [story instantiateInitialViewController];
[_window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

3/ I (tried to) destroy the UI in `applicationDidEnterBackground`

```
UINavigationController *vc = (UINavigationController *)_window.rootViewController;
_window.rootViewController = nil;
_window = nil;
```

4/ I scheduled a timer every 2s with a NSLog inside in a view controller

5/ With the code above, the view controller is not destroyed and timer is still called when the app is in background

Any idea ?

Comment: You are responsible for inavlidate timers etc when your app is going in background and there is no need to kill the UI. The system knows that. The only thing that works is just your background service.

Comment: @Andrea wouldn't the UI needlessly eat memory, which would get the app killed quicker when in the background?

Comment: As far as I know (except for 3d games) is the system that manages the UI intended as backing layers. If you load images with imageNamed they goes into a cache and that cache is empty automatically when the app goes into background. Instead if you load an array of images with other mothods is your responsability to get rid of them during a memory warning that could happen since the app is active in background. If you handle that you are already freeing up memory http://stablekernel.com/blog/view-controller-lifecycle-in-ios6/